# can't dump anonymous module error (Using Rails delayed_job on method in module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, delayed-job

I am trying to use the [delayed_job queuing system](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) on one of my methods. When I move the method to its own module, it runs without error. However, I would like to run the method in the same module to make the code a bit cleaner but I'm receiving the error "can't dump anonymous module error".

```
module TeamActions

    def team_members(options)
            client = options[:client]
            team = options[:team]

            self.delay.create_all_permissions(team,client)
    end

    def self.create_all_permissions(team,client)
            team.memberships.each do |member|
                ClientPermission.create(client: client, user: member.user)
            end
    end

end
```

Comment: hmm, not sure, but to me it looks like there is something wrong with calling instance methods instead of singleton methods...
team_members is an instance method, so self is an instance of the module, so you are calling delay on the instance. create_all_permissions is a singleton method, called on the module.
I am really just guessing here: Did you try "def create_all_permissions(team,client)" instead of "def self.create..."?

Comment: Hello, yes I did try it like that and received the same "can't dump anonymous module error".

Comment: Imagine you are the delayed job worker, and this job has been scheduled.  You pull the job out of the database.   You know the name of the method you are supposed to call is `create_all_permissions`, and that the arguments are `team,client`.  But you don't know what module it's in.  Try enqueing the job without a worker running.  Then in the console, pull that job record out of the `delayed_jobs` database and take a look at what's inside.